# Drop rows with multiple keys in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes, `df1` and `df2`.

df1:

```
contig  position   tumor_f  t_ref_count  t_alt_count
1     14599  0.000000            1            0
1     14653  0.400000            3            2
1     14907  0.333333            6            3
1     14930  0.363636            7            4
```

df2:

```
contig  position
1     14599
1     14653
```

I would like to remove the rows from df1 with matching contig, position values in df2.

Comment: @Aert probably because OP simply spelled out his requirement. Stackoverflow doesn't like *can you give me codez* kind of questions. If OP has tried something, and posted the result here, then this question could have been good.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way. I am sure there are other solutions,

```
conpos_del <- with(df2, interaction(contig,position,drop=T))
subset(df1, !interaction(contig,position,drop=T) %in% conpos_del)
```

Comment: Maybe using unique() around the interaction forming `conpos_del`?

Comment: You could, but it would make no difference for %in% !

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty, but it works

```
df1[!paste(df1$contig, df1$position) %in% paste(df2$contig, df2$position),]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `match()` function with negative subsetting:

```
df1 <- data.frame(contig = c(1,1,1,1), position = c(14599, 14653,
    14907, 14930), other = c(1,2,6,7))

df2 <- data.frame(contig = c(1,1), position = c(14599, 14653))

df1[-na.omit(match(df1$position, df2$position)), ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1[ ! with(df1, interaction(contig, position) %in% 
                  with(df2, unique(interaction(contig , position))) , ]
```